# Cannot handle multiple requests using `StreamSocketListener`

Tags: c++, win-universal-app, windows-10

Putting existing problems aside, I was moving to test the ability of the server to handle multiple requests in [my server application in universal app](https://github.com/anhoavu/BackgroundServer). It appears that it cannot handle multiple requests as advertised in the documentation. (See the source file [ServerTask.cpp](https://github.com/anhoavu/BackgroundServer/blob/master/BackgroundServerTask/ServerTask.cpp) and [MainPage.xaml.cpp](https://github.com/anhoavu/BackgroundServer/blob/master/BackgroundServer/MainPage.xaml.cpp) for the related code and the README for background information.)

In background i.e. suspended mode, subsequent requests end up with

**WinRT information: The object identifier does not represent a valid object.**

EDIT: Just run again and the background `ServerTask` is not executing at all. When `ClientTask` is triggered, the app is automatically woken up from Suspended state and `netstat` indicates that it is listening to the appropriate port but not responding to the requests.

While in the foreground mode, subsequent requests end up with

**WinRT information: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.**

which mean that I should not do

```
delete args->Socket;
```

after handling the request in `MainPage::OnConnectionReceived`. If I delete that line, it can handle 2-3 requests and still end up with the same exception. On the other hand, is it the right way to go, leaving open sockets?

How should it be implemented?

Comment: What and where is happening?

Comment: @kiewic I edit the description. I change the client background task to make 10 requests instead of one. One of them gets handled correctly. Afterwards, I always get the mentioned exception. Feels like the socket activity trigger is only for a one shot scenario. I suspected my machine is not working properly and tried resetting my machine and reinstalling all updates. Is there a way to check if my system is operating correctly?

Comment: Please put the relevant parts of your code here. The links will become invalid over time and then this question is of no use for other visitors of the site.

Comment: @Werner Henze I think it would be better to have the full project so interested people can clone & see the problem directly. It would be helpful if stackoverflow provide code repository feature like a GitHub account to keep tab of the referenced code where we can place full project instead of inserting code snippets in questions which take significant efforts to set up.

Comment: @VuAnHoa Disagree. If other programmers experience the same Problem as you, how should they see this easily looking at your question? They can only see this if the relevant (short) code (http://www.sscce.org/) is in your question. They will not see it if they have to browse through a complete Git project. Remind: SO is not only for helping you with your Problem, it is also for helping other programmers coming here in future looking for a solution.